# How to provide the current route or view to the layout in ExpressJS?

Tags: node.js, express

I want to be able to dynamically reference JavaScript and Stylesheets depending on which page a user is on in Express.  I thinking the best way to do so (though I'm open to suggestions) is to pass the current view to the layout page.

For example;

Given the url `http://example.com/trees`

I would want to have some logic in layout.jade that said something to the effect of:

`script(src="/javascripts/{view}.js")`

Which would get rendered as:

`<script src="/javascripts/trees.js"></script>`

Any suggestions or best practices for doing this?

Comment: try __jade[0].filename and if that's the answer, I'll explain how I know it is.

Comment: thks @jcolebrand that was the simplest solution for me.

Comment: You're welcome. Do you care to know how I derived that from the source code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

req.route is the matched route, so things like req.route.path etc are available, or of course req.url which may be parsed. With express 2x you can expose these values to views automatically using "dynamic helpers" or res.local()

Comment: note to express 3 users: dynamic helpers are deprecated in favor to app.locals http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.locals

Answer (score 0):

There are no best practices for doing this, since Express doesn't provide Rails like url helpers, so I think you're approach is fine.

Answer (score 0):

The easy answer is to just put ALL your javascript into a single file and be done with it.  Ditto for CSS.  See the [Ruby on Rails asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) for details.  You are probably making your life more complicated than necessary and also less efficient by having different javascripts on different pages.

However, since you asked, the answer for javascripts is easy. Just put the extra `<script>` tags in the view, not the layout. Problem solved.  CSS doesn't work as cleanly because the `<link>` tags need to be inside the `<head>`.  In this case, I define the styles I need as an array of strings and loop over that in my layout template.  So in my route I set up a local variable such as

```
locals.css = ['/css/one.css', '/css/two.css']
```

Then just loop over that in your template and generate one `<link>` tag for each.